# Чи є коректним вживання абревіатури ВУЗ?

Tags: скорочення

Навчальні заклади користуються абревіатурою ВУЗ. Чи не суперечить це правилам української мови?
Зустрічається "ВУЗ" і "ВНЗ", обидва варіанти є правильними?

Comment: ВУЗ — вищий [учбовий](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3072) заклад. Якщо те слово є, то і абревітура є; якщо того слова нема, то й абревіатура недоречна. Тобто це фактично дублікат [запитання № 3072 «Чи ми можемо вживати слово „учбовий“?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3072).

Comment: дійсно не варто повторюватись, ви можете доповнити вже наявне запитання, а це видалити

Answer (score 2):

В коментарях доречно підмічено, якщо є слово учбовий отже є і абревіатура.

З СУМ-11

> **[УЧБОВИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/uchbovyj)** Те саме, що **навчальний**. *Київ тепер є найбільшим культурним центром республіки, в ньому працює Академія наук і Академія
>   архітектури, десятки вищих учбових закладів і наукових інститутів*
>   (Петро Панч, В дорозі, 1959, 264).
>
> **[НАВЧАЛЬНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/navchaljnyj)** . Стосовний до навчання, пов'язаний з ним. *У процесі навчання учні усвідомлюють не лише навчальні предмети, а й
>   свою власну навчальну діяльність* (Радянська психологічна наука..,
>   1958, 382);

Зокрема у СУМ-20 присутння така абревіатура

> **[ВУЗ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16915&page=566)**  у, ч., **застаріле**. Скорочена назва вищого навчального закладу; ВНЗ. – *Я її торік іще зустрів на вулиці. “І чого б я ото, –
>   кажу, – по-дурному час гаяв! .. ну для чого ви в Києві сидите? ..
>   Поступили б до якогось вузу, почали б учитись абощо”* (Б.
>   Антоненко-Давидович); *Вчилися вони, ці дівчатка, в радянських школах,
>   кінчали десятилітки, йшли до вузів, мріяли бути лікарями, інженерами*
>   (Остап Вишня); *Наприкінці 80-х я кілька семестрів викладала естетику
>   в одному з мистецьких вузів Києва* (О. Забужко); *Студенти і викладачі
>   вузу часто приймають закордонних гостей* (з газ.).
>
> **[ВНЗ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=182680&page=506)** невідм., ч. Скорочення: вищий навчальний заклад; виш. *Кожен
>   ВНЗ повинен зберегти власне унікальне “обличчя”, яке формують персонал
>   і студенти* (з наук. літ.); *Навчальний посібник “Курс загальної
>   астрономії” ми адресуємо студентам університетів та інших ВНЗ, а також
>   учителям шкіл і гімназій* (з навч. літ.); *Правильне управління
>   отриманими коштами, підвищення конкурентоспроможності кожного окремого
>   ВНЗ на ринку освітніх і наукових послуг вимагає високої професійної
>   підготовки керівних кадрів, а також відповідної законодавчої бази* (із
>   журн.); *Важливе завдання для українських ВНЗ – розвивати свою
>   автономію* (з газ.).

***Оскільки ВУЗ є застарілим, більш вживаним є ВНЗ***